# Spring MVC inject `Environment` in constructor but not in request handler method

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC `@Controller` named `MyController`. I can inject the Spring `Environment` in its constructor:

```java
public MyController(Environment environment) {
  …
}
```

But if I try to inject the same `Environment` into a request handler, it fails:

```java
@GetMapping
public String getFoo(Environment environment)
```

The error message is:

> `No primary or single unique constructor found for interface org.springframework.core.env.Environment`

I note that I can inject the HTTP servlet request in the handler with no problem:

```java
public String getFoo(HttpServletRequest request)
```

Why can I inject `Environment` in the controller constructor, but not in a handler method?

Where in the documentation can I go to get a list of things that can only be injected in one place or the other?

Comment: Because in constructor it is (implicitly) `@Autowired` ..and in controller (method)  it complies (only!) with ["(mvc) method arguments"](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-arguments) (where `Environment` would be interpreted as `@RequestParam/ModelAttribute`...last row ;)

Comment: HttpServletRequest is special (2nd row;)

Comment: But the key point: constructors of a controller/bean/component/... *significantly differ* from "annotated controller methods"

Comment: If you need to access `Environment` within your controllers, you can use the one (and normally only) "from constructor"..

Comment: I try to make it an answer!:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

["Annotated Controllers"](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-controller)

- ["Handler Methods"](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-methods)

  - ["Method Arguments"](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-arguments) are *very specific* parts of spring-web (/[-webflux](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-ann-arguments)), handled and populated by (very) specific "converters, filters, handlers, adapters, (holy etc.)" and (should) conform with the linked (version specific;( documentation.

Whereas "dependency injection", auto-wiring (as `Environment`) are very general parts (spring-context,-beans,-core) of "spring infrastructure". Best to start: [at the top](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#spring-core)!:)

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are saying that Spring MVC controller request mapping methods don't technically do full Spring dependency injection auto-wiring; rather they only support a limited number of things they know how to inject, documented at the links you gave.

Comment: You got me right, @GarretWilson... Especially the last part (as the doc states). So most correct: "...they only support a limited number of things they know how to inject, documented at the links you gave."

Comment: Well the documentation isn't very clear on the distinction and leaves it to the reader to figure it out. I found one sentence that implies the difference: "`@RequestMapping` handler methods have a flexible signature and can choose from a range of supported controller method arguments and return values." I guess "supported … arguments" implies that handler methods _only_ support the listed arguments, and that otherwise normal autowiring doesn't apply. I think the documentation could have been a bit more explicit. Thanks for pointing me to this list.

Comment: This issue came up again in https://stackoverflow.com/q/76039575 . It took me a little while, but then I remembered the answer here, so this answer is serving extra duty. I'll add a bounty to assign to this answer because it's proving so useful. Thanks.