# Spring inject interface in controller request handler method when implementation annotated

Tags: java, spring, dependency-inversion

I have a simple `FooBarRepository` interface. I have a single implementation called `DefaultFooBarRespository`, which looks like this:

```java
@Repository("fooBarRepository")
public class DefaultFooBarRepository implements FooBarRepository {
  …
}
```

I know that Spring is instantiating `DefaultFooBarRepository` and giving it a bean name of `fooBarRepository`, because in my Thymeleaf view I can do something like:

```html
<li th:each="fooBar: ${@fooBarRepository.getFooBars()}" …
```

As we all know, it's best to program to interfaces. After all I might want to wire up a different implementation of `FooBarRepository` at some point. So in my MVC controller `FooBarController` I try to inject the interface:

```
@GetMapping
public String getFooBars(FooBarRepository repository) {
  …
}
```

That results in an error:

> `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No primary or single unique constructor found for interface ….FooBarRepository`

Spring I suppose is trying to create an instance of `FooBarRepository`, not realizing that the `DefaultFooBarRepository` it already created is an instance of `FooBarRepository`.

I imagine I could create a separate class annotated with `@Configuration` and have a method that returns an `FooBarRepository`. I could even probably inject the `DefaultFooBarRepository` instance into this method and return it as the `FooBarRepository`.

But why should I have to do all that? Spring is already creating a `DefaultFooBarRepository`, adding it to the context, giving it a bean name, etc. How can I tell Spring simply to register the `DefaultFooBarRepository` with the `FooBarRepository` interface rather than the `DefaultFooBarRepository` implementation? Is there another annotation or an annotation parameter I can add to `DefaultFooBarRepository` or something?

*Update:* And this is even stranger: in `FooBarController` I tried to inject `DefaultFooBarRepository`:

```
@GetMapping
public String getFooBars(DefaultFooBarRepository repository) {
  …
}
```

Then I get another error saying that one of the parameters of the `DefaultFooBarRepository` constructor is `null`—specifically a `@ConfigurationProperties` annotated class `AppProperties`. It appears that in the controller `GET` handler it's trying to create an instance of `DefaultFooBarRepository`. But Spring should have already scanned the classes and instantiated both `AppProperties` and `DefaultFooBarRepository`. And we know it did, because as I mentioned the Thymeleaf view can access `@fooBarRepository.getFooBars()`. What am I missing here? Why can't the controller see any of the bean classes the the view can see?

Comment: Try removing @Repository from the interface.  Or add @Primary to `DefaultFooBarRepository`.  And see @Conditional when there are multiple instances to choose from.

Comment: Hi G. , Same reason/issue as with [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75860160/592355): While it is *theoretically* possible to `@Autowire` "methods" (im- vs. ex-plicitly!) ..."I never saw this" except for -getter/setter, -`@Configuration#Bean`, -"constructor" "methods"… With "handler methods" you create an ambiguity (for the handling of method parameters) So "implicit autowiring" is no option (for "handler methods") at all! ..I will/can try/test "explicit auto wiring", but have few hope.. :)

Comment: Also when (trying to) doing so, you have to make (at least few) considerations about "scope".... While a "controller/repository/service/..." is "singleton" by default... A "handler method" is "request[-session]-scopable" ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is the same one in [Spring MVC inject `Environment` in constructor but not in request handler method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75860160) : Spring doesn't do normal injection in the controller request handlers, but instead only supports a limited number of objects. Full dependency injection only works in the constructor.

So I moved the injection to the controller constructor, and it worked fine, even for the interface:

```java
public FooBarController(FooBarRepository fooBarRepository) {
  …
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmhmh, "explicit auto-wiring" (so *using* the `@Autowired` annotation) seems NOT to help!

- [https://start.spring.io](https://start.spring.io/#!type=maven-project&language=java&platformVersion=3.0.5&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=17&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&dependencies=web)
- and very basic sample:

  ```java
  package com.example.demo;

  /* import org.springframework...*/

  @SpringBootApplication
  public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
     SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Component
    static class SomeBean {

    }

    @Controller
    static class DemoController {
     @GetMapping("/hello")
     public @ResponseBody String hello(@Autowired SomeBean someBean, String q) {
      System.err.println(someBean);
      return "Hello, " + q;
     }
    }
  }
  ```

... works NOT as expected! (`someBean` reference changes with every request ;(;(

... "SomeBean" is treated as ["Controller method argument"](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-arguments), and corresponds with (last row/entry):

> Any other argument

> If a method argument is not matched to any of the earlier values in this table and it is a simple type (as determined by `BeanUtils#isSimpleProperty`), it is resolved as a `@RequestParam`. Otherwise, it is resolved as a `@ModelAttribute`.

(spring-web populates this "param/attrib" via existing default/resolvable constructor)

---

Doing (e.g.) so:

```java
@Controller
static class DemoController {

  @Autowired SomeBean someBean;

  @GetMapping("/hello")
  public @ResponseBody String hello(String q) {
    System.err.println(someBean);
    return "Hello, " + q;
  }
}
```

(moving `someBean` to an  "autowired field",) "fix-/changes everything"/works as expected.

---

#### Overall Scenario

> Accessing a (rarely changing) "list of values" via thymeleaf:spring-mvc

[`@ModelAttribute`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ModelAttribute.html) (on controller(!)/method level) is documented/recommended by both, [spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-method-args) and [thymeleaf](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmvcaccessdata.html).

```java
// in your @[Rest]Controller (annotated) class (to be tested with: @ControllerAdvice!=;)
@ModelAttribute("fooBars")
public List<FooBarVO> fooBars(/* also with arguments like @PathVariable, @RequestParam, ...*/) {
  return fooRepository.findAll(); // or even fooService.findAllCached()... fooRepository/-Service comes through "normal" spring dependency injection (of your choice... manual/auto/exotic ((final/)field/accessor/(constuctor/)parameter...)
}
```

To access (in all templates rendered by this controller class) like:

```html
<xx th:each="foo : ${fooBars}">
  ...
```